# SynEdit: Can't Display True Type Fonts Correctly

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, synedit

I've downloaded a SynEdit version from a Chinese website (with lots of improvements), but as the version on Sourceforge it doesn't support true-type fonts (such as Tahoma); it displays them separated with a space.

Anything I can do about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SynEdit does not support variable-width fonts. Only fixed-width ones. Long time ago, when SynEdit was being developed actively such request was made by one user and rejected due the rewrite needed to support variable-width fonts. For this reason I dropped SynEdit from my toolbox. I now use Scintilla, a much better editor.

Comment: but its the supported in the Unicode Version of SynEdit, also Scintilla is coded in C, which means that it cant be edited (for me) :( any other solution?

Comment: @killercode: Unicode support does not mean it supports variable-width font. Scintilla is written in C++ but can be used with other languages, including Delphi. As I said, it is not an easy task to change SynEdit. And the current development of SynEdit is pretty low.

Comment: thats not what i meant, i meant the unicode version supports these fonts, how can i make the non-unicode version do that? and i can use Scintilla, but i cant modify it, since i dunno much c++

Comment: There is not way unless you do heavy changes in the code. Check the SVN log history of SynEdit. Development stalled. I use Scintilla because it being seriously developed and is being used by some major players.

Comment: The Lazarus fork is still being developed. Though it is used for programming purposes, so fixed font only too. I never really liked what I saw from Scintilla, but that could be configuration issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a real editor like TRichView.

It supports every kind of font spacing, is written in Delphi, and handle Unicode efficiently (even with old Delphi versions).

You can use TRichView with syntax highlighting. There is some source code sample in http://www.trichview.com/resources

But TRichView is not free.